# Validate programatically generated form fields on client side and server side

Tags: java, jquery, forms, validation, struts2

I have a struts2 form that is programatically generated upon request. The element names for all the fields are the same namely `idA` and `paramValue` because I am passing the form values as array and looping through it for database inserts. Inserts are now OK, but I am still finding out how to validate the form.

Here's the form:

```
<s:iterator value="sysParamList" var="sysParam">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <strong><s:property value="paramName" /></strong>
            <input type="hidden" name="idA" value="<s:property value="id" />" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="paramValue" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

The properties in my action are declared like

```
private String[] idA;
private String[] paramValue;
```

And I pass these in my DAO as-is. The DAO does the looping through the array for database insert.

I can validate forms using jquery.validate IF the form is hard coded in the JSP.

Comment: I don't see how the form could be *hard coded*?

Comment: What kind of validation do you need?

Comment: @RomanC I'm just saying that I won't be asking this question if the form fields are not generated inside a loop.

Comment: @AleksandrM I need first the server side validation.

Comment: Use `validate` method in your action class.

Comment: @SciasTwentyThree So what the loop stops you from running field validators or do you want to use non-field validator, or programmatic validation?

Comment: @AleksandrM Yeah, I know that, however, I am validating form that is programatically generated. The number of input field will rely on the number of records in the database.

Comment: @RomanC I have no idea what kind of validation is appropriate for this. Maybe a `for` loop on the `validate` method but I don't know if that's the right way to go.

Comment: I have seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9970133/1540638) but is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Yeah, it's called a programmatic validation, it run along with other config-based validators.

Comment: @RomanC How can I validate input formats in the `validate` method using this? I know input format checking can be done via validation xml in struts but only if the form elements are hard coded in the JSP.

Comment: Parse it with a pattern, you can use regex field validator.

Comment: What conditions do you want to check? Not nulls, regex....?

Comment: @AleksandrM Right. Not nulls and regex.