# How to: Struts 2 validating dynamic forms array

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, validation, struts2

I read through this
[Struts2 Validation for an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969024/struts2-validation-for-an-array)

and it makes sense, but wished person (Quaternion) would explain how to

"rewrite the above to specifically name fields (with indexes) in which case you can use , and you'll use the addFieldError method. For details on these tags see http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1.2/docs/tag-reference.html"

This is what I have:

```jsp
<s:form action="saveOrUpdateAction" method="get">
    <s:token/>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td> Fund </td>
            <td> Award Code </td>
        </tr>
        <s:iterator value="gfeListWithEmptyCode">
            <tr>
                <td> <s:property value="sfafund "/> </td>
                <td> <s:property value="awardcode"/>
                    <input type="text" name="codeArray">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </s:iterator>
        <s:token />
        <s:submit key="Submit2"/>
    </table>
</s:form>
```

Part of my Action:

```java
public void validate()
{
    if (fund == null || fund.trim().length() != 5 )
    {
        System.out.println("testing+++++++++++++++++++1");
        addFieldError("fund","Fund requires 5 characters.");
    }
    if (code == null || code.trim().length() != 3 )
    {
        System.out.println("testing+++++++++++++++++++2");
        addFieldError("code","Fund requires 3 characters.");
    }


    if (gfeListWithEmptyCode !=null)
    {

        int index = 0;
        for (GiftFundEntity giftFundEntity : gfeListWithEmptyCode)
        {
            if ( codeArray[index]!=null && codeArray[index].length() < 3 )
            {

                System.out.println("testing+++++++++++++++++++3");

                // technically, this is not possible to do because it requires codeArray[index] and not a string.

                addFieldError("codeArray","Code requires 3 characters.");
                index++;
            }
        }
    }


    try
    {
        this.execute();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

During validation, the red error message does not show up on the jsp page for obvious reasons because codeArray isn't listed by the indexes.  How do I get this to work?   *** Please note*** the array is dynamic.

I looked through the struts documentation and searched through stackoverflow, but I don't see how it can be done.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is Struts 2 treats the codeArray variable inside the Action class as an Array:     String [] codeArray;  This is not documented.